# On the integral of a function that looks like inverse Gamma function?

Tags: integration, special-functions, gamma-function

How to evaluate the following integral?
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-\alpha-1} \exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\gamma_i}{x+\beta_i}\right)\mathrm{d}x~,$$ 
where the parameters $\alpha, \gamma_i, \beta_i$ $> 0$ where $1 \leq i \leq n$.

For $n = 1$ and $\beta_1 = 0$ the integrand resembles an inverse gamma function, which can be evaluated with the help of an inverse gamma distribution. However, when there is a scalar added to $x$ and there are a few terms summed as shown here, this becomes a bit complicated. How can this be evaluated analytically?

Comment: The restrictions on $\beta_i$ and $\gamma_i$ imply the exponential is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$, while the restriction on $\alpha$ imply the integral has a lower bound proportional to $\epsilon^{-\alpha}$ (or $-\log(\epsilon)$ if $\alpha=0$) as its lower limit $\epsilon$ approaches $0$ from above.  Therefore this integral diverges.

Comment: Assume that the support of this function is defined for $x > 0$. A similar definition exists for inverse gamma distribution. Please have a look at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution). Hence, more precisely, I am evaluating the integral from $0_+$ to $\infty$.

Comment: That is exactly what I have *had* to assume from the expression you gave.  Your integral diverges.  Unless you want to assess the rate at which it diverges, there's nothing left to say.  That link goes to the familiar Wikipedia page on the Inverse-Gamma distribution, *but your integral does not involve that distribution*: the addition of the $\beta_i$ changes things completely.

Comment: Alright. I understand your point.